# Charge conjugation in arbitrary basis

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra, charge-conjugation

Consider the matrix $C = \gamma^{0}\gamma^{2}$.

It is easy to prove the relations

$$C^{2}=1$$
$$C\gamma^{\mu}C = -(\gamma^{\mu})^{T}$$

in the chiral basis of the gamma matrices.

---

1. Do the two identities hold in any arbitrary basis of the gamma matrices?
2. How is $C$ related to the charge conjugation operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's instead use the [Majorana basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Majorana_basis) for Gamma matrices, which I'll denote by a tilde. The main thing about this basis is all the gamma matrices are imaginary so the Dirac equation $(i\tilde{\gamma}^{\mu}\partial_\mu-m)\tilde{\psi}=0$ is real, and solutions can be broken up into purely real and imaginary parts. So if $\tilde{\psi}$ satisfies the equation so does $\tilde{\psi}_c\equiv\tilde{\psi}^{*}$. This is what charge conjugation looks like in this basis.

In a different basis of gamma matrices, say the chiral basis, we need to do a unitary transformation $\psi=U\tilde{\psi}$. Then
$$\psi_c=U\tilde{\psi}^*=U(U^\dagger \psi)^*=UU^T \psi^*\equiv\gamma^0C\psi^*,$$
where in the last line we defined the matrix $C$ $$\gamma^0C\equiv UU^T.$$
So above is the formula for charge conjugation in an arbitrary basis, where $C$ is defined in terms of the unitary transformation from the Majorana basis.

The reason we include the factor of $\gamma^0$ is so $C$ satisfies the second identity you mentioned. This follows from $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0=\gamma^{\mu\dagger}$ which is preserved by unitary transformations.

From this we can prove the generalization of the identities you listed
$$C\gamma_\mu C^{-1}=-\gamma_\mu^T$$
$$-CC^*=1$$

What is not necessarily general is $C=C^{-1}$. I presented the same argument here as in the paper [arXiv:1006.1718](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1718v2) so you might want to look at that.

Comment: Is the charge conjugation anti-unitary? I.e. it is the application of compliex conjugation followed by the C matrix?

Comment: @Craig, Sort of yes. As in my answer (5 years ago!) $\psi_c = \gamma^0 C\psi^*$. Just to be clear these are transformations acting on spinors not the Hilbert space.

Comment: the answer appears more nuanced in fact! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667594/complex-conjugation-in-time-reversal-t-symmetry-v-s-in-charge-conjugation-c