# Regarding the action of Time reversal on Dirac spinors

Tags: unitarity, parity, time-reversal-symmetry, charge-conjugation, cpt-symmetry

I'm inquring about the difference between notions of time reversal found in Streater & Wightman's "PCT, Spin and Statistics, and All That", and [this accepted answer from Chiral Anomaly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/667594/complex-conjugation-in-time-reversal-t-symmetry-v-s-in-charge-conjugation-c). While both agree $\mathcal{T}$ is anti-unitary and $\mathcal{C}$ is unitary, and that
$$\mathcal{C} \psi(t,x) \mathcal{C}^{-1} \propto \psi^{c}(t,x)$$
they disagree in that the book says on page $19$ section $(1-45)$
$$\mathcal{T} \psi(t,x) \mathcal{T}^{-1} \propto \psi^{c} (-t,x)$$
while the above answer says
$$\mathcal{T} \psi(t,x) \mathcal{T}^{-1} \propto \psi(-t,x).$$

Is this merely different conventions? Or is one incorrect?

Comment: The full answer to my question can be found in "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" by Schwartz, section 11.6 on page 198

Comment: Another reference: section 1.1 in [arXiv:1712.08639](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08639) acknowledges both conventions.

Answer (score 2):

There are two definitions of time reversal, one of which changes particle to antiparticles. The second, the Wigner definition, does not and is the one usually used these days.

Comment: Could you maybe expand on how these different time reversals affect the CP operators? Or the interpretation of CPT? Would the Wightman CPT send particles to particles, while the Wigner CPT send particles to anti-particles?